# Getting rid of empty entries in core data swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'll show you an image of my mock up app running: [image]

I need to get rid of those empty entries up top. I'll show you my storing, clearing and gettting methods.

storing:

```
func createGetContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{

        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)

         return (appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext)!

    }

    private func createMessageWithText(text: String, friend: Friend, minutesAgo: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        //setting up the message as a Message() type and filling in the parameters
        let message = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Message", into: context) as! Message
        message.friend = friend
        message.text = text
        message.date = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(-minutesAgo * 60)

    }

    //setting up the data
    func setupData(){

        clearData()
        //batchDelete()

        let context = createGetContext()

        let adagio = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friend", into: context) as! Friend
        adagio.name = "Adagio"
        adagio.profileImageName = "photo_adagio"


        let glaive = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friend", into: context) as! Friend
        glaive.name = "Glaive"
        glaive.profileImageName = "photo_glaive"

        let ringo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friend", into: context) as! Friend
        ringo.name = "Ringo"
        ringo.profileImageName = "photo_ringo"

        let celeste = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friend", into: context) as! Friend
        celeste.name = "Celeste"
        celeste.profileImageName = "photo_celeste"

        createMessageWithText(text: "This is boredom at its best!", friend: adagio, minutesAgo: 2, context: context)
        createMessageWithText(text: "Somebody! get a soda.", friend: adagio, minutesAgo: 3, context: context)
        createMessageWithText(text: "Im going to cut you into little pieces.", friend: adagio, minutesAgo: 1, context: context)
        createMessageWithText(text: "Eat axe, bitch!!", friend: glaive, minutesAgo: 4, context: context)
        createMessageWithText(text: "Anybody wants to be my pingpong ball?!", friend: glaive, minutesAgo: 0, context: context)
        createMessageWithText(text: "Drunk right now!", friend: ringo, minutesAgo: 2, context: context)
        createMessageWithText(text: "Stars and Boom!", friend: celeste, minutesAgo: 6, context: context)

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Saved!!!!!")
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

        getMessages()

    }
```

Clearing methods (2 i tried):

```
func clearData() {

        //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
        let fetchRequestMessage: NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest()

        let fetchRequestFriend: NSFetchRequest<Friend> = Friend.fetchRequest()

        do {
            //running the fetch request and adding to the array.
            friends = try createGetContext().fetch(fetchRequestFriend) as [Friend]

            for friend in friends! {
                //looping and deleting
                createGetContext().delete(friend)
            }

            //go get the results and add it to an Array to be deleted
            messages = try createGetContext().fetch(fetchRequestMessage) as [Message]

            for message in messages! {
                //loop through array and delete every message
                createGetContext().delete(message)

            }
            //have to save the context after deleting
            try (createGetContext().save())

        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }

    }
    //delete the everything, (bug: does not display anything on the tableView if run)
    private func batchDelete() {

        let fetchRequestMessage: NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest()

        let fetchRequestFriend: NSFetchRequest<Friend> = Friend.fetchRequest()

        let requestFriend = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequestFriend as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

        let requestMessage = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequestMessage as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

        do {

            try createGetContext().execute(requestFriend)
            try createGetContext().execute(requestMessage)


        } catch let err {

            print(err)
        }
    }
```

and the fetch method:

```
//fetching the messages
    func getMessages () {

        if let friends = fetchFriends() {

            for friend in friends {
                print(friend.name!)


                //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
                let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest()
                //sort the array by time/date
                fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
                //filtering the pull with friend's name equal to friend.name!
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", friend.name!)
                //limit pull to 1 item
                fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

                do {
                    //go get the results and add to array for display
                    let fetchedMessages = try createGetContext().fetch(fetchRequest) as [Message]
                    //appending the messages into the message array
                    messages?.append(contentsOf: fetchedMessages)

                } catch {
                    print("Error with request: \(error)")
                }
                //sorting the messages array...throwing a nil...need to fix
//                messages?.sort(by: { $0.date?.compare($1.date as! Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending })

            }
        }


    }
```

I think those entries came from tests that failed. As you can see, I've tried to empty the entities and also tried pulling them into an array and deleting them one by one. None works. Help me pls. :) Or atleast help figure out how to not add those in the array so they wont show up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want to get rid of old test data, how I understood, you can simply delete the app from device/simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After countless testing, I ran the batchDelete() method in the viewDidLoad instead of inside the setupData() method which runs right after the batchDelete() and this worked.

Lesson here is, dont wait for answers. Always try trudging through while waiting for answers.